# Closure caches a variable?

Tags: javascript

There is something wrong with my code, but I can't find what it is. The first time I call registerStartDateValidation, the value of the startDateValidation variable in the defineKeyword closure is of course the same than what was affected outside the closure. But the second time, the variable is reaffected with another value, but the value of startDateValidation in the defineKeyword is still equal to the value of the first time we call registerStartDateValidation. Does the closure cache the variable?

```
Tv4.prototype.registerStartDateValidation = function (attributes) {
    var helper = this;
    var dateNames = Object.keys(attributes);
    var startDateName = dateNames[0];
    var startDateString = attributes[startDateName];
    var endDateName = dateNames[1];
    var endDateString = attributes[endDateName];
    var startDateValidation = helper.startDateValidation(startDateString, startDateName, endDateString, endDateName);

    console.log(startDateValidation)//First time equal "true", second time equal "false"

    tv4.defineKeyword('startDate', function (data, value) {
        if (value === 'startDate') {
            console.log(startDateValidation)//First time equal "true", second time still equal "true"
            return startDateValidation
        }
    });

};
```

Note that there is nothing making an ajax request, that could mess up the order the functions are called.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: The result you're getting doesn't sound likely, and a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/k43X4/) shows both logs should return the same thing. Is helper.startDateValidation in any way async, or is there something else going on that is async etc.

Comment: No it's not async, but I noticed if I set startDateValidation as a member data: this.startDateValidation, startDateValidation has the good info. But I don't want to set it as a member variable...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, a closure won't cache the variable, so there is something else going on in your code. Reducing the problem to a simple complete example that demonstrates the problem will usually make it obvious where the problem is coming from, or at least help other people figure it out.

However, since it looks like you're referring to is [this project](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4), it may be possible to figure out what's going on. `Tv4.defineKeyword()` appends new functions to a list if it is called multiple times for the same keyword. Since you're calling `tv4.defineKeyword` (note the lower-case 't') and not `helper.defineKeyword` or `this.defineKeyword`, it looks like each call to `registerStartDateValidation` will affect the same instance, so you are almost certainly *adding* a validation function when you meant to replace it.

Comment: I know I am adding a validation and not replacing it, and TV4 is just my custom helper that wraps tv4. What I don't get is why the tv4.defineKeyword callback in my registerStartDateValidation function does not consider the new values that are passed in the outer scope. But thanks for confirming a closure does not cache.

Comment: @Maxwell If you're looking for more info/help with this problem, I think you're going to need to post a complete example.